# Can you equip multiples of the same item?

Tags: dead-of-winter

If a survivor has an item equipped (the lighter, for example), can that character equip identical items and would they be able to use all of them as normal?

Answer (score 0):

There are no limitations on equipped items, so yes, and yes.